# Underscore function in Backbone acting strangely

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have been working on a Rails app using Backbone on the frontend. It has two models, publication and article. I wrote the following function in the publications backbone router and it supposed to delete the specified publication and all it's related articles. It deletes the publication just fine but I am running into an issue when it comes to deleting the articles. Here is the code:

publications_router.js

```
  delete_publication: function(id){
    var publication = new SimpleGoogleReader.Models.Publication({id: id});
    publication.fetch();
    publication.destroy();


    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();

    articles.fetch({
      success: function(data){

        _.each(data.models, function(item){
          if (item.toJSON().publication_id == id) {
            console.log(item);
          }
        });
      }
    });

  }
```

This works great for printing each item in the console. However, if I change the console.log(item) line to say:

```
item.destroy();
```

It will only destroy every other item. Obviously I would like to correct this so the function destroys all the items and not every other one.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and what we can do to fix it?

Comment: It's mutating the array by `splicing` an element out (the array is shortened within the loop every time it destroys). You need to loop manually.

Comment: What do you mean manually? Please elaborate:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter out the items you want to destroy.

```
var tobeDeleted = _.filter(data.models, function(item){
          return (item.toJSON().publication_id == id);
        });
```

... and then destroy

```
_.invoke(tobeDeleted, "destroy");
```

Comment: `data` should be a collection so you can `data.filter(function(item) { ... })` instead of messing around with the `models` property. And `item` should be a model so `item.get('publication_id')` would be better than `item.toJSON().publication_id`. There's also a typo: `_.filer` should be `_.filter`.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks palanik!

Comment: You are welcome.

@mu is too short - Thanks. Typo is fixed. 
I restricted my response to OP's questions on _ and didn't bother to venture into backbone models. I think OP should heed to your advice on good practices.